# Inverting a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse

Consider the following series
$$S_1 := \sum_{n\in\mathcal{S}} a_n,$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is some countably infinite set (I am mostly interested in the case $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{Z}^N$). Is there a (systematic) way to represent $\frac{1}{S_1}$ in the form
$$ \frac{1}{S_1} = \left(\sum_{n\in\mathcal{S}} a_n\right)^{-1} = \sum_{n\in\mathcal{S}} b_n,$$
for some coefficients $b_n$ as functions of $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathcal{S}}$?

NB: since the summation is not well-defined unless we fix an ordering on $\mathcal S$, it is necessary to either set $N=1$ and use the natural ordering on the integers, or to fix an ordering on $\mathcal S$ (but this would probably prove a tad more difficult).

Comment: I don't see how this is well-defined.  Even in the case of "traditional" series like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ the order of the terms can affect the answer.  How would this make sense on an unordered infinite set like $\mathbb{Z}^N$?

Comment: @Randall If I assume convergence, does the order still matter? Do you have an example for that?

Comment: Yes:  any conditionally convergent series can have its terms rearranged to converge to **anything**.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Even setting aside convergence and order issues (so let's say everything is absolutely convergent) it's sort of delicate what this should mean: certainly there are *many* series converging to $1/S_1$ (for example the series whose first term is $1/S_1$ and the rest are $0$), and certainly we can write such a thing in terms of $a_n$ (take, say, $b_0 = 1/\sum a_n$ and $b_n = 0$ for $n \neq 0$).

Comment: As a toy example you can maybe make it more interesting by imposing some structure, like requiring that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are somehow of similar "type", e.g. if $\sum a_n$ is geometric, can we make $\sum b_n$ geometric? (Yes, and it's not so hard (do the algebra, with the binomial theorem you can make the $b_n$ into fairly cute expressions in terms of $a_n$) but be wary of convergence again.)

Comment: It would be interesting if there was a canonical way of doing this indeed.